# Export SharePoint Webpart using csom

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Does anyone know if it possible to export web parts using CSOM in Office 365. The scenario I want to enable is to move publishing pages (with web parts embedded) from one Office 365 tenancy to another. My initial research would indicate that it is not possible in client side code - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick.

```
 var limitedWebPartManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        var webPartDefinitons = limitedWebPartManager.WebParts;
        clientContext.LoadAndExecute(webPartDefinitons);
        foreach (var webpartDefintion in webPartDefinitons)
        {
            try
            {
                var webPartId = webpartDefintion.Id;
                var webPartXML = limitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart(webPartId);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                clientContext.Load(webpartDefintion, def => def.ZoneId, def => def.Id);
                clientContext.LoadAndExecute(webpartDefintion.WebPart, w => w.Title, w => w.ZoneIndex, w => w.Properties);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
```

Comment: As Waldek Mastykarz write: the ExportWebPart method should be available since the March 2016 SharePoint Online CSOM update (source: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/export-web-parts-csom/), See as well: https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-march-2016

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint export only a LimitedWebPartManager through CSOM.
It is very limited (hence the name) and can achieve only limited actions.
(change title of a WebPart, read informations).

However, I would recommend you to use the /_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx service.
(Add service Reference, http://yoursharepoint/_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx,

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential();
credentials.UserName = "username";
credentials.Password = "secret";
credentials.Domain = "domain";

var svc = new WebPartPagesSvc.WebPartPagesWebService();
svc.Credentials = credentials;

var result = svc.GetWebPartPage(filename, WebPartPages2Svc.SPWebServiceBehavior.Version3);

Console.Write(result);
```

Hope this help.